# Changing MPMoviePlayerController content not working with performSelectorInBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am trying to change the content of my `MPMoviePlayerController` method with function running in background.But my *content is not getting changed*.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateVideo) withObject:nil];
```

This is my *viewDidLoad method where I start loading a video*.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    VideoView *videoView = [[VideoView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 293, 320)];
    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"My Movie4" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [controller.view setFrame:videoView.bounds];
    [videoView addSubview:controller.view];
    [self.videoviewer addSubview: videoView];
    [controller prepareToPlay];
    [controller play];
}
```

Where VideoView is a subclass of UIView.My updateVideo function is like this.

```
-(void)updateVideo
{
[controller setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video2" ofType:@"mp4"] ]];
[controller prepareToPlay];
[controller play];
}
```

But the video content is not getting changed when the function is called which is running in background.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to change the content in the `background thread` ?

You **can't change UI element** in the `background thread`. You have to execute this task in the `main thread`.

Try to do this :

```
[self updateVideo]
```

Or this if you want, but I recommend you to use the first method.

```
-(void)updateVideo
{
    [controller setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video2" ofType:@"mp4"] ]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [controller prepareToPlay];
        [controller play];
    });
}
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: I tried this code and still the issue persists. Earlier i was changing the content of a UIImageView in the background method. But why it is not changing in case of Video.Still confused.

Comment: My main thread is continuously doing a microphone listening function in the foreground that based on the sound frequency i want to change the video.. I was able to do this with an image and UIImageView. I dont want to disrupt the microphone function which is running in foreground.